# Spring Boot Data how to get count of fields (columns), those are changed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a project, in which I need to create the history(audit) of entity after each update(edit), when the number of updated columns equal or more than 3. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for hibernate called "audit/enver". Here is an example project: https://github.com/enexusde/Java-Spring-Boot-JPA-Enver-Audit-Hibernate-Tools-Reversengineer

Basically add this to your pom-(xml-node project/dependencies)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then add

```
@EnableJpaAuditing
```

to your appconfig.java

Then you can access old tuples using the [AuditReader](https://github.com/enexusde/Java-Spring-Boot-JPA-Enver-Audit-Hibernate-Tools-Reversengineer/blob/master/src/main/java/de/e_nexus/codereview/audit/CoolHistory.java#L26):

```
AuditReader r = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
```